# How can I make the layout file in Rails to change depending on each page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Complete noob at Rails here. I'm helping out a colleague with his website, just so I can get some experience with rails. I'm really struggling with it.

I've created a navigation bar in app>views>layouts>application.html.erb.
From what I understand, things created here will be applied to all pages. 
I need the navigation bar to contain text that corresponds to the header text of the page that the user is currently on.

For example, if the user is on the Home page, I want text on the navigation bar to read "Home". The home page already contains a

## Home

.

Here is the html I've got in application.html.erb,

```
<div id = "navigation-bar">
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to 'Home', home_index_path, class: "btn btn-success" %></li>
  <li class = "text-center"> <!-- I would like the header text here --> </li>
  <li id = "right"><button type="button" name="button" class = "btn btn-default">Contact</button></li>
  <li id = "right"><button type="button" name="button" class = "btn btn-default">About</button></li>
</ul>
```

```
<style>

#navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

</style>
```

As I said, complete rails noob here. Be patient with me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the provide method as follows:

## application.html.erb

```
<li class = "text-center"> <%= yield :title %> </li>
```

## whatever_the_page_is.html.erb

```
<%= provide :title, "Yolo" %>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!